# Whatsapp & factory reset

Tags: samsung, whatsapp-messenger

I have recently factory/hard reset my Samsung Galaxy Advance. Apparently the Whatsapp application doesn't exist in my phone anymore. Does this mean, my account is deleted or I still need to delete it cause the my contact for whatsapp is still seen on my friend's phone.

Comment: Account is not deleted. Download app again and manually delete the account.

Answer (score 2):

Your account will not have been deleted, so you will still show up as a contact for other people. On your phone you will need to first re-install WhatsApp. Then if you want to delete your account go to "Settings" -> "Account" -> "Delete my account".

Answer (score 2):

unistalling the whatsapp will not delete your account .. you need to do it manually.

install whatsapp again then do it following step:
step 1: go to Settings.
step 2: click on Account
step 3: click on "Delete my account".